# ASP.NET MVC Linq Query to compare too variables?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Is there a way I could get this query to work?

```
var employeesSU = from s in db.HolidayRequestForms
                          where s.Employee.Site.SiteName == searchSitehols || searchSitehols == null || searchSitehols == ""
                          select s;


        var querythpmpro = (from r in db.HolidayRequestForms
                            where r.Employee.Site.SiteName == employeesSU.FirstOrDefault()
                            group r by r.MonthOfHoliday into g
                            select new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Sum(h => h.HoursTaken) }
               ).OrderBy(e => e.Value);
```

I currently get this error:

```
 Error  4   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'HolidayTracker.Models.HolidayRequestForm' C:\Projects\HolidayTrackerMainProject\HolidayTracker - Working - 04-03 - Copy\HolidayTracker\Controllers\MetricsController.cs   170 39  HolidayTracker
```

is there a way around this error? Or can I not just compare the two?

Comment: In which line does this error occure? I guess it's the `s.Employee.Site.SiteName == searchSitehols`... what is `SiteName`? Obvioulsy it's not a `string`.

Comment: Or if `SiteName` is a `string` then obviously you cannot compare it to an element of `employeeSU`, a `HolidayRequestForm` is not a string.

Comment: Yes SiteName would be a string. And yes HolidayRequestForm is not a string but a sql table I guess but I only want one element from it. But thanks that makes sense now

Comment: I see that you only want one element, hence `FirstOrDefault()`, but how exaclty do you want to compare a row of your table to a string?

Comment: You see I am using this with google charts and I need a way in the UI for the user to pick a site (which I am doing with a dropdown hence the employeeSU variable) but I'm not even sure if it'll work that way

Comment: Just tried it out following what you said and it worked!! thanks @RenéVogt

Answer (score 0):

```
  var querythpmpro = (from r in db.HolidayRequestForms
                            where r.Employee.Site.SiteName == employeesSU.FirstOrDefault().Name // or whatever field you want to compare
                            group r by r.MonthOfHoliday into g
                            select new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Sum(h => h.HoursTaken) }
               ).OrderBy(e => e.Value);
```